# Dagger-Hilt : Why we must annotate Activities which has no injection

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger, dagger-hilt

Why we must to annotate activities which contains fragments on it ?

Activity has no @Inject but fragments need some dependencies .
I annotate fragments as `@AndroidEntryPoint` but crash until set this on parent activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't start a Fragment without an Activity. You have to annotate your Activity with `@AndroidEntryPoint` because your fragment is a HiltComponent now. When you don't annotate your Activity with `@AndroidEntryPoint` Hilt would not create a component for this activity and thus could not start the fragment because it didn't create the ActivtyComponent yet.

> Hilt activities need to be attached to Hilt applications. Hilt
> fragments must be attached to Hilt activities.

See here: https://dagger.dev/hilt/migration-guide (2. Migrate Activities and Fragments)